# Translation is continuous in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for $L_{loc}^{1}$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$. Let $(\tau_{y}f)(x) := f(x - y)$. Then $\|\tau_{y}f - f\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{d})} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow 0$. Is this result still true for $f \in L^{1}_{loc}$?

Alternatively, given a function $f \in L^{2}(B(0, R))$ for some large $R$, is it true that $\|\tau_{y}f - f\|_{L^{2}(B(0, R))} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: You should be able to construct a function $f \in L_{loc}^1$ such that $\Vert \tau_y f - f\Vert_2 = \infty$ for all $y>0$ (or all $y<0$) (lets say $d=1$). For example $x \mapsto x^{-2/3} \chi_{(0,\infty)}$. You can even arrange $f \in L^1$ this way. For the second question: What do you mean by $f \in L^2(B(\dots))$? Do you mean that $f$ vanishes outside of $f(\dots)$, or do you assume that $f$ can be (essentially) arbitrary outside of $B(\dots)$?

Comment: Ah you are correct for the first question. For the second question, I mean suppose for some $R$ (fixed, does not depend on $f$, we could just take it to be 1 to be concrete), I knew that $\int_{B(0, R)}|f|^{2} < \infty$, then is it true that $\int_{B(0, R)}|\tau_{y}f - f|^{2} \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: If you know $\int_{B(0,R')}|f|^2 <\infty$, then $\int_{B(0,R)} |\tau_y f -f|^2 \to 0$ will hold for each $0<R<R'$, as can be seen by considering $g = f \cdot \chi_{B(0,R')}$ (where $\chi_{B(0,R')}$ is the indicator function of the ball), since on $B(0,R)$ you will have $\tau_y g = \tau_y f $ for small enough $y$. For $R=R'$, the claim is probably false by an analogous argument to the one above.